# Toast with compose ui is crashing with exception "viewtreelifecycleowner not found from androidx.compose.ui.platform.composeview"

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-toast

```
val context = LocalContext.current
        Button(onClick = {
            val toast = android.widget.Toast(context)
            val composeView = ComposeView(context)
            composeView.setContent { ToastUi() }
            toast.view = composeView
            toast.show()
        }
        ) { Text(text = "Show toast") }

 @Composable
 fun ToastUi() {
        Row {
            Icon(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_success_colored),"")
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(12.dp))
            Text("sample")
        }
    }
```

on button click the application crashes with exception "viewtreelifecycleowner not found from androidx.compose.ui.platform.composeview"

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti trying to make a toast with custom ui, with its ui written in compose, since toast.setView accepts a view as a parameter so i wrapped my composable in a ComposeView

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti the first Toast that is accepting context as a parameter is android.widget.Toast and second one with no parameter passed is the below written composable, i guess naming them same created the confusion

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti cleared the code, hope its more clear now

Comment: Custom toasts are [deprecated](https://cs.android.com/android/_/android/platform/frameworks/base/+/7b843abc1c7cd53096557909f31216b93c3ca674) in favour of SnackBar.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti, yes the recommended approach is snackbar but atleast it should not crash, i trying to identify where am i going wrong, is it the usage of the toast class or something is wrong with the way i am adding compose to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val toast: Toast = Toast(this).apply {
        duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG + Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        view = ComposeView(this@ToastActivity).apply {
            setOwners()
            setContent { TestProjectTheme { ToastLayout() } }
        }
    }

private fun ComposeView.setOwners() {
if (ViewTreeLifecycleOwner.get(this) == null)
    ViewTreeLifecycleOwner.set(this, context as LifecycleOwner)
if (ViewTreeViewModelStoreOwner.get(this) == null)
    ViewTreeViewModelStoreOwner.set(this, context as ViewModelStoreOwner)
if (ViewTreeSavedStateRegistryOwner.get(this) == null)
    ViewTreeSavedStateRegistryOwner.set(this, context as SavedStateRegistryOwner)}
```